# Dificuldade em por as imagens direitas porém elas ficam na diagonal

Tags: javascript, html

Está aqui o meu  código:

```js
    var myIndex1 = 0;
    var myIndex2 = 0;
    var myIndex3 = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
      var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
      var x3 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides3");
      for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
        x1[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
        x2[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x3.length; i++) {
        x3[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      myIndex1++;
      if (myIndex1 > x1.length) {myIndex1 = 1}
      x1[myIndex1-1].style.display = "block";
      myIndex2++;
      if (myIndex2 > x2.length) {myIndex2 = 1}
      x2[myIndex2-1].style.display = "block";
      myIndex3++;
      if (myIndex3 > x3.length) {myIndex3 = 1}
      x3[myIndex3-1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
    }
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-section" >
    <img class="mySlides1" src="1.png" width="250" height="200" hspace="250px" vspace="50px" border="3">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="2.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="250px" vspace="50px" border="3">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="3.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="250px" vspace="50px" border="3">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="4.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="250px" vspace="50px" border="3">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="5.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="250px" vspace="50px" border="3">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="6.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="250px" vspace="50px" border="3">
        <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro1.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="530px" vspace="50px" border="3">
        <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro2.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="530px" vspace="50px" border="3">
        <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro3.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="530px" vspace="50px" border="3">
        <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro4.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="530px" vspace="50px" border="3">
        <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro5.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="530px" vspace="50px" border="3">
        <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro6.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="530px" vspace="50px" border="3">
            <img class="mySlides3" src="larive1.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="810px" vspace="50px" border="3">
            <img class="mySlides3" src="larive2.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="810px" vspace="50px" border="3">
            <img class="mySlides3" src="larive3.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="810px" vspace="50px" border="3">
            <img class="mySlides3" src="larive4.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="810px" vspace="50px" border="3">
            <img class="mySlides3" src="larive5.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="810px" vspace="50px" border="3">
            <img class="mySlides3" src="larive6.jpg" width="250" height="200" hspace="810px" vspace="50px" border="3">

</div>
```

Comment: Lucas melhor seu título. Seja objetivo com apenas 5 ou 6 palavras. O restante vc coloca no corpo de texto da pergunta. Coloque também o seu HTML e CSS para facilitar na resposta.

Comment: se eu por o código todo  não sei porque mas corta o html e css e um pouco java

Comment: Lucas use a ferramenta "Trecho JavaScript/HTML/CSS (Ctrl-M)" no campo de pergunta. É a sétima opção, ao lado de inserir Imagem.

Comment: desculpe. sou novo  em  programação nao percebi  o que disse

Comment: @LucasSintra copiei para o snippet, agora falta você editar adicionando o css e explicar melhor o que você deseja fazer.

Comment: eu  não  usei css para as imagens. basicamente o que eu  quero fazer é: ter 3 slides de imagens  a rodar automaticamente. eu já consegui fazer isso  mas o problema e que elas não ficam na mesma linha. eu já usei  o hspace e o vspace para ver se ficam  na mesma linha mas não  da.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue código de exemplo. Rode ele e veja se resolve seu problema:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slide Show</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w3-content w3-row">
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img class="mySlides1" src="1.jpg" width="250" height="200" border="3">
      <img class="mySlides1" src="2.jpg" width="250" height="200" border="3">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-container">
      <img class="mySlides2" src="3.jpg" width="250" height="200" border="3">
      <img class="mySlides2" src="4.jpg" width="250" height="200" border="3">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-container">
      <img class="mySlides3" src="5.jpg" width="250" height="200" border="3">
      <img class="mySlides3" src="6.jpg" width="250" height="200" border="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myIndex1 = 0;
    var myIndex2 = 0;
    var myIndex3 = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
      var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
      var x3 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides3");
      for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
        x1[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
        x2[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x3.length; i++) {
        x3[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      myIndex1++;
      if (myIndex1 > x1.length) {myIndex1 = 1}
      x1[myIndex1-1].style.display = "block";
      myIndex2++;
      if (myIndex2 > x2.length) {myIndex2 = 1}
      x2[myIndex2-1].style.display = "block";
      myIndex3++;
      if (myIndex3 > x3.length) {myIndex3 = 1}
      x3[myIndex3-1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(carousel, 1000);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Só precisa substituir com os nomes das imagens, mas este código já está funcionando.

Comment: oi, deu. mas removeu  o meu  border e alterou a minha letra. da para por de volta?

Comment: No exemplo não tem letra alguma. Qual letra você está falando? Você pode escolher o tipo de fonte que quer via CSS ou usando os estilos do próprio W3.CSS.

Comment: é assim  eu  antes tinha escolhido  arial para o  meu  titulo e com o  <link...> mudou  para outro  tipo. isso é o menos importante. Sabe porque o border desapareceu?  Sei  que lhe é pedir muito  mas será que me pode dizer o que o java script faz? tipo uma nota para ver para que serve mais ou menos. ser puder agradecia-lhe imenso

Comment: https://becode.com.br/javascript-para-iniciantes-origens-o-que-e-para-que-serve/

Answer (score 0):

Não validei seu javascript, mas a solução visual que me pareceu estar procurando eu resolvi com CSS, inclusive removendo todos atributos redundantes dos seus elementos. Confira se é isso que você está buscando.

```js
var myIndex1 = 0;
    var myIndex2 = 0;
    var myIndex3 = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
      var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
      var x3 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides3");
      for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
        x1[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
        x2[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x3.length; i++) {
        x3[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      myIndex1++;
      if (myIndex1 > x1.length) {myIndex1 = 1}
      x1[myIndex1-1].style.display = "block";
      myIndex2++;
      if (myIndex2 > x2.length) {myIndex2 = 1}
      x2[myIndex2-1].style.display = "block";
      myIndex3++;
      if (myIndex3 > x3.length) {myIndex3 = 1}
      x3[myIndex3-1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
    }
```

```css
.w3-section img{
  height:200px;
  width:250px;
  border:3px solid black;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-section" >
    <img class="mySlides1" src="1.png">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="2.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="3.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="4.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="5.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="6.jpg">
    
    <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro1.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro2.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro3.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro4.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro5.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="cozinheiro6.jpg">
    
    <img class="mySlides3" src="larive1.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="larive2.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="larive3.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="larive4.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="larive5.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides3" src="larive6.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: copiei o seu codigo e pus no meu e não  deu  continua a fazer a mesma coisa que estava a fazer antes. ou seja as imagens ficam na diagonal  em  vez de ficarem  retas

Comment: removeu os seus vspace e hspace?